# How to draw a Seq2Seq RNN model with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw this RNN encoder-decoder model, with tikz found here:

https://github.com/harvardnlp/seq2seq-talk/blob/master/slidescmu.pdf

This is a nice diagram, but unfortunately I'm not sure how to start designing it. Could someone help me get started? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: (i) determine node styles (shapes rectangle, rectangle split, circle) (ii) determine their position (with loop, chains, ...) (iii) connect nodes with arrows (solid, dashed) :). For start see similar TikZ examples, for examples in http://www.texample.net/ or here on the site.

Comment: Did you notice that there is some TikZ code in that repository? Edit: not for that diagram, but at least for some colored, divided boxes, and arrows, which is a large part of that diagram.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a not-quite-complete replication of the diagram you posted, inspired by [the code in the seq2seq-talk repository](https://github.com/harvardnlp/seq2seq-talk/blob/master/rnntikzpicz/goldrnnlm.tex):[image: seq2seq diagram]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      hid/.style 2 args={
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        draw=#2,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        fill=#2!20,
        outer sep=1mm}]
      % draw input nodes
      \foreach \i [count=\step from 1] in {the,blue,house,{{$<$eos$>$}}}
        \node (i\step) at (2*\step, -2) {\i};
      % draw output nodes
      \foreach \t [count=\step from 4] in {la,casa,azul,{{$<$eos$>$}}} {
        \node[align=center] (o\step) at (2*\step, +2.75) {\t};
      }
      % draw embedding and hidden layers for text input
      \foreach \step in {1,...,3} {
        \node[hid={3}{red}] (h\step) at (2*\step, 0) {};
        \node[hid={3}{red}] (e\step) at (2*\step, -1) {};    
        \draw[->] (i\step.north) -> (e\step.south);
        \draw[->] (e\step.north) -> (h\step.south);
      }
      % draw embedding and hidden layers for label input
      \foreach \step in {4,...,7} {
        \node[hid={3}{yellow}] (s\step) at (2*\step, 1.25) {};
        \node[hid={3}{blue}] (h\step) at (2*\step, 0) {};
        \node[hid={3}{blue}] (e\step) at (2*\step, -1) {};    
        \draw[->] (e\step.north) -> (h\step.south);
        \draw[->] (h\step.north) -> (s\step.south);
        \draw[->] (s\step.north) -> (o\step.south);
      }  
      % edge case: draw edge for special input token
      \draw[->] (i4.north) -> (e4.south);
      % draw recurrent links
      \foreach \step in {1,...,6} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{add(\step,1)}
        \draw[->] (h\step.east) -> (h\next.west);
      }
      % draw predicted-labels-as-inputs links
      \foreach \step in {4,...,6} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{add(\step,1)}
        \path (o\step.north) edge[->,out=45,in=225] (e\next.south);
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```